# Convert Hex String into unsigned char[]

Tags: objective-c, hex, unsigned-char

I am asking this question mainly because I have searched through this site for possible solutions and none have worked out the way I hoped.

I would like to perform converting this Hex String into an unsigned char[].

`NSString *text = @"0043600001";` into
`unsigned char dataSmall[] = {0x00, 0x43, 0x60, 0x00, 0x01}`

I need the hexadecimal representation **0x##** because I am sending a host that accepts messages in `hexadecimal format` only. Am I right to say, I too need `NSScanner` to perform these steps to separate 2 characters? Really lost and confused on what I need to do.

This are the steps to connect and send the hexadecimal message to the host:

```
unsigned char dataSmall[] = {0x00, 0x43, 0x60, 0x00, 0x01}
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:dataSmall length:sizeof(dataSmall)];
```

P.S, I do not know about the `NSData` part, but it seems to work when I use that NSData line to send hex messages to the host. So I am leaving it as it is. Currently, `dataSmall[]` is hard coded and I would like to find out how to deal with it dynamically. Would appreciate all helps here.

**EDIT 1**
Ah, I missed out an important information. The hex data is an `ISO8583` message itself.

Comment: Can you explain where the hex string is coming from? It seems very strange that you would have a bunch of hex data as a string.

Comment: It is a little confusing to me at first, so I am sorry if I am not giving you the answers you are looking for. For now, it would be from `TextField`. But I have yet to do something about it, like converting ASCII string into hex data. And yes, it would be weird to convert hex string into hex data.

Comment: If you want to convert text to `NSData` that you can send to a server then simply get the `NSData` like this: `NSData *textData = [someTextField.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`. That's it. You now have the bytes of the text encoded in UTF-8 and ready to send to the server. The server can now use that data to recreate the UTF-8 string. There is no need for all of this hex conversion.

Comment: Yea, I already tried that. But the server requires a specific message to get a response. Any other messages will only have a failed message error. I updated my question, I forgot something important. The message has to be in ISO8583 format.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSScanner *scan = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:@"1F61E"];
unsigned int val;
[scan scanHexInt:&val];
char cc[4];
cc[3] = (val >> 0) & 0xFF;
cc[2] = (val >> 8) & 0xFF;
cc[1] = (val >> 16) & 0xFF;
cc[0] = (val >> 24) & 0xFF;
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc]
               initWithBytes:cc
               length:4
               encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"[%@]", s);
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code, will test it out and get back to you on this comment. But can I ask, what is this `1F61E`? and those val comparison of 0, 8, 16, 24. What are they suppose to do?

Comment: 1f61E is hexvalue and (0,8,16,24) are binary shifting ,you might have heard about binary shifting.

Comment: This code just gave me a sad face emo icon. How can I even use implement this to my app?

Comment: actually what do you want to do with your string? would you please put some string to covert, and after converting it to hex string what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Firstly, I would need a 16-digit number and a another value with 2 decimal placing (price tag).  Then I would need to use the `ISO 8583` messaging -- which currently, I am still trying to find out how to use -- if it is in `hex string` results. Convert that `hex string` into an `unsigned char[]`. Did I lost you there?